# Prove that sequence $x_{n}=\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2^2+1}+...+\frac{1}{2^n+1}$ has a limit.

Tags: limits

Given following sequence:
$$x_{n}=\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2^2+1}+...+\frac{1}{2^n+1}$$
I have to prove that this sequence has a limit. So I think first of all I should prove that this is convergent sequence. But I have absolutely no idea how to do this because I haven't seen any examples with such complicated sequence before. So can you give me some hint how to do my first step? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint $\frac{1}{2^k+1} < \frac{1}{2^k}$ and $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2}+\ldots = 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that $\dfrac{1}{2^n+1}\le \dfrac{1}{2^n}$ to show it's bounded and show it's increasing.

Comment: Maybe you should write $\lt$ instead of $\le$?

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik $\le$ is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison test with the sequence $y_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}
$Prove that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Then $x_n$ has a limit.